# how to create a shortcut for libre office calc file in Lubuntu 18.04

Tags: libreoffice, shortcuts, lxde

I tried creating a shortcut using 'menu editor' In the command section of the editor i entered

> libreoffice --calc smb://home/drpjkurian/Dropbox/CLINIC2018.ods

It did not work Did I miss something?

Comment: what is your LUbuntu Version?

Comment: It will be more practical to create a symbolic link for quick access to your file from a different location.

Comment: Have you not tried super+4 buttons on keyboard??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed a software known as 'Menu editor' from software centre and added this line in the command line box **

> localc /home/dr/Cliinic2019.ods

**
The command line directs lo calc to open the file from the destination

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-mint-84/desktop-shortcut-to-a-file-4175594332/). The trick is to create a link by dragging the document to the Desktop while holding down CTRL+SHIFT